# Where is the big key in Dragon Roost Cavern in Legend of Zelda Wind Waker? And how do I get there?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube, zelda-wind-waker

How do I get the big key in Dragon Roost Cave? I MIGHT know where it is but I might be wrong. But how to do it is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its at the top left of this map (floor 1) (mouse over to see text)

> You need to stun the magtail and put it on the switch to lower the fire ring

[image: Dragon Roost Cavern Map]

Comment: oh there was a switch?? I guess I didn't look close enough. Thanks!